# Integral of an L_p function

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, lp-spaces

Let $p \ge 1$ and $f$ be a Lebesgue measurable function on $\mathbb R$ such that
$\int_{\mathbb R} |f(x)|^pdx < \infty$. Show that,
$$\int_{\mathbb R} |f(x)|^pdx =\int_0^{\infty}
pt^{p-1}\lambda(\{x : |f(x)| > t\})dt$$
where $\lambda$ denotes the Lebesgue measure.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Layer_cake_representation

Comment: See here for the most general case https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3823829/show-that-int-bbb-r-fxp-dx-int-0-infty-p-tp-1-lambda-lef/3823837#3823837